# Convert Qt Project to Dev C++ project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, dev-c++

So basically I have a "PLAIN c++" Qt project created with:

```
qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-mingw48_opengl-x86-offline
```

And I need to open it with "Dev C++ 4.9", quite simple que pro file looks like:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    palabra.cpp \
    menu.cpp \
    app.cpp \
    ahorcado.cpp

HEADERS += \
    palabra.h \
    menu.h \
    app.h \
    ahorcado.h \
    keypress.h
```

Need to do it ASAP.

Comment: The last stable version of Dev-C++ only supports up to Windows 2000...

Comment: @sjdowling I know but the teacher wants Dev-C++ so I'm forced to

Comment: @Shf checking all the import options, creating the files inside Dev-C++ and filling them with my data, exporting qt project with qmake to visual c++ (but that didn't even work). Anyway I guess it's too late now, I didn't give my homework, I guess I failed.